# shape file > data frame > using ggplot and joining on GEO ID with other data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, rgdal, r-sf

The county shape file is only available as a national shape file (2017 TIGER/Line® Shapefiles: Counties (and equivalent), https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2017&layergroup=Counties+%28and+equivalent%29

I want to select just one state (e.g. Pennsylvania). So,

```
# read county polygons
counties <- readOGR(dsn="tl_2017_us_county", layer="tl_2017_us_county") 
# subset to PA counties 
PA_counties <- subset(counties, counties@data$STATEFP == "42")
```

HOWEVER, when I try and create a data frame and map, I'm getting the error:
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lon' not found

```
# create a data frame
PA_counties.df <- as.data.frame(PA_counties)
PA_counties.dfFORT <-fortify(PA_counties.df, region = "GEOID")

gg<-ggplot()
gg <- gg +geom_polygon(data =PA_counties.dfFORT, aes(x=lon, y=lat, group=group,
        fill=NA), color = "blue", fill=NA, size = 0.5 
gg <- gg +coord_map()
gg
```

Help? I'm hoping to create this map; merge the data with another file by GeoID, and fill some of the counties (e.g. for GeoID xxx if =1 then fill with blue, etc).

This must be a very common mapping use case scenario? Grateful for any tips?

Best,
Lori

Comment: Take a look at [`sf`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/index.html) for this kind of task

Comment: Look at the names in your data frame after `fortify`: you have `INTPTLAT` and `INTPTLON`, not `lat` and `lon`

Answer (score 1):

I did some troubleshooting that I encourage you to do as well. First, look at the names of your fortified data frame: you have columns such as `INTPLAT`, `INTPLON`, and `GROUP`, instead of `lat`, `long`, and `group`.

When you call `as.data.frame` on the spatial data frame and then call `fortify`, you're not getting what I think you would expect. If you take a closer look at the output you get from these two functions, it seems to be centroids or some other point, such that you have just one point per county, and the coordinates are factors, not numbers. You instead need to call `fortify` on the spatial data frame itself. You should expect a data frame with thousands of rows, because there are many points needed to make up the polygon shape of each county.

Note that I used `tigris::counties` to get the shapefile because I couldn't read a downloaded file to make the reprex, but I'm pretty sure the shapefile is identical.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)

counties <- tigris::counties(cb = T)

# counties <- readOGR(dsn="tl_2017_us_county", layer="tl_2017_us_county") 
PA_counties <- subset(counties, counties@data$STATEFP == "42")
PA_counties.dfFORT <- fortify(PA_counties, region = "GEOID")

names(PA_counties.dfFORT)
#> [1] "long"  "lat"   "order" "hole"  "piece" "id"    "group"
```

Then you can use `geom_polygon` as you expected:

```r
ggplot(PA_counties.dfFORT, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = NA, color = "blue") +
  coord_map()
```

[image]

An easier and more flexible way is to use `sf`. Again, you can use `sf::read_sf` on the shapefile; for making a reprex, I called `sf::st_as_sf` on the spatial data frame I'd gotten with `tigris`. `sf` lets you use `dplyr`-style functions to do operations like filtering, adding columns, and calculating summaries.

```r
counties_sf <- st_as_sf(counties)
# counties_sf <- read_sf("tl_2017_us_county")
pa_counties_sf <- counties_sf %>%
  filter(STATEFP == "42")
head(pa_counties_sf)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 9 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -80.36087 ymin: 39.72002 xmax: -74.7215 ymax: 40.74368
#> epsg (SRID):    4269
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
#>   STATEFP COUNTYFP COUNTYNS       AFFGEOID GEOID       NAME LSAD
#> 1      42      003 01213657 0500000US42003 42003  Allegheny   06
#> 2      42      017 01209173 0500000US42017 42017      Bucks   06
#> 3      42      041 01209176 0500000US42041 42041 Cumberland   06
#> 4      42      055 01213670 0500000US42055 42055   Franklin   06
#> 5      42      061 01213672 0500000US42061 42061 Huntingdon   06
#> 6      42      071 01209181 0500000US42071 42071  Lancaster   06
#>        ALAND    AWATER                       geometry
#> 1 1890889706  37411488 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.36078 4...
#> 2 1565408723  45201371 MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.48406 4...
#> 3 1412834155  12521844 MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.62503 4...
#> 4 2000052118   1544300 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.09914 3...
#> 5 2265337403  37851955 MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.2567 40...
#> 6 2444606396 103423673 MULTIPOLYGON (((-76.72162 4...
```

`sf` is also very easy to use with `ggplot` because as of `ggplot2` version 3.0.0 released a few weeks ago, `ggplot` ships with a `geom_sf` function that reads your `sf` object's `geometry` column automatically. You can go straight from reading a shapefile to plotting it.

```r
ggplot(pa_counties_sf) +
  geom_sf(fill = NA, color = "blue")
```

[image]

As an example of how you can then merge in another dataset with your shape, I made some dummy data with a letter for each county, then just called `dplyr::left_join` to join it with the `sf` data frame, then plotted. Hope that helps get you started!

```r
pa_data <- data_frame(
  GEOID = pa_counties_sf$GEOID
) %>%
  mutate(type = sample(c("A", "B"), size = nrow(.), replace = T))

pa_counties_sf %>%
  left_join(pa_data, by = "GEOID") %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = type), color = "blue")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Sf package and the geom_sf function from ggplot2 make this task quite simple.

```
library(sf)
counties <- st_read("tl_2017_us_county") 
# subset to PA counties
# note with sf you can treat it just like a data.frame and there is no need to call @data 
PA_counties <- counties[which(counties$STATEFP == "42"),] 

# use geom_sf to plot an sf object easily
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = PA_counties)
```

Comment: Sorry for my tardy thank you on this! I got better at R basics, and studied your feedback here.

Answer (score 0):

I used the feedback above and a couple other sites for reference ( also switched to census tracts). Two key things that weren't obvious to a newbie 1) it helps to switch the GeoID to char 2) fortify hasn't worked probably if the names aren't "long" "lat" "group" etc.

```
# Percent reporting no participation in leisure time physical activity 
# https://chronicdata.cdc.gov/500-Cities/500-Cities-Census-Tract-level-Data-   GIS-Friendly-Fo/k86t-wghb/data

# New York State census tracts
# https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2018&layergroup=Census+Tracts 

library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)

census <- readOGR(dsn="tl_2018_36_tract", layer="tl_2018_36_tract")
nyc_census <- subset(census, census@data$COUNTYFP %in% c("005", "061", "047", "081","085"))
nyc_census@data$GEOID<-as.character(nyc_census@data$GEOID)
study <- fortify(nyc_census, region = "GEOID")

lpa <- read.csv(file ="500Cities.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
lpa <- lpa[, c(3,45,46)]
lpa <-mutate(lpa, id=as.character(TractFIPS),
             LPA_CrudePrev =as.numeric(LPA_CrudePrev),
             lpa_percent =(LPA_CrudePrev/100))

study2 <- left_join(study, lpa, by=c("id"))

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data =study2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill=lpa_percent), color="grey50") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("red", "white", "cadetblue"),
                values = c(1,0.5, .3, .2, .1, 0)) +
                coord_map(xlim = c(-74.26, -73.71), ylim = c(40.49,40.92))
```